# Karma test Angular 2 w/ tsconfig.json setup for alternative paths

Tags: angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "cart/*": [ "app/cart/*" ],
      "customer/*": [ "app/customer/*" ],
      "device/*": [ "app/device/*" ],
      "services/*": [ "app/shared/services/*" ],
      "components/*": [ "app/shared/components/*" ],
      "mocks/*": [ "app/shared/mocks/*" ]
    }
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  }
}
```

When I run `npm test` I am getting failures because karma can't find the paths to imports when they are defined like this in `tsconfig.json`

`example.service.ts`

`import { ExampleService } from 'services/example';`

Comment: Does the _app_ work?

Comment: @peeskillet: yes.. everything works fine in the app. Just when I run `npm test` do I get errors in karma.

Comment: @PhillipBerger did you find any solution related to this. I'm facing same problem please reply if you figured it out.